# Cyclocross touring, studs for SPD shoes?

Tags: touring, shoes, cyclocross, spd

I just bought my first bicycle shoes (Specialized, SPD) and got four mountable studs. I'm planning on touring for about a month. Mostly on roads, perhaps occasionally on dirt tracks and larger trails.

I'm not too concerned about weight, so I started thinking of whether it would be a good idea to mount them before going or not. I'm thinking either of mounting them permanently or not mounting them at all, as I don't want to bring extra tools/stuff with me on the trip that I might not end up using.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Studs are a bad idea if you might need to do any walking.  Using SPD cleats, on the other hand, is a good idea.

Comment: They'll wear out quickly on hard surfaces. Change them for flat-headed screws. If you're looking for sturdier replacements get rugby or football studs. They'll fit as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you plan to do a lot of sprinting up muddy hills to jump barriers, the studs are just extra weight that makes annoying noises when you're walking around.

SPD is great for touring since you can easily walk around in the shoes, the studs detract from that without adding much benefit.

You can get small "set screws" to fill the holes where the studs would go. This prevents
the threads getting filled with dirt in case you decide to use them later.

https://www.boltdepot.com/Metric_set_screws_Allen_Cup_point_Stainless_steel_18-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing them.  Studs are only useful for steep hike a bike scenarios on loose dirt or clay (something that the spikes can bite).  These were really intended for XC race situations, where some climbs are too steep to ride so you need to throw the XC bike on your shoulder and run like you stole it!

In all the tours I have never done, including dirt road tours, I have never found a need for studs.  The bikes are often too heavy to push up inclines steep enough to require studs.

Walking on the asphalt, studs are slippery and could cause you to slip at an inopportune time.  For example, when you put a foot down while on the saddle, you will be on your toes.  Pushing off on the studs when on pavement could be difficult.

About the only situation where I think you might find them handy is if you encounter a ruby scrummage.  Here toe cleats are a must!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say mount them.  The weight is negligible and if you are a person that finds them useful, they'll be there.  Make sure you use some LocTite or similar on the threads.  If you don't and the rattle out during your trip, you'll wish you had.

That being said, I been through a few pairs of MTB shoes and I have never found the studs useful for anything I have done.  I spend a lot of time riding on ice, and they are too blunt to provide traction on compacted snow or ice.  Sidi makes spikes that are quite a bit sharper and longer than normal.  I used them for awhile as they offered good purchase on ice, but found they had a tendency to stick in floor grates and snap off.